# "ldap_add: Naming violation (64)" error when configuring OpenLDAP

Tags: 10.04, configuration, ldap, openldap

I am following the [Ubuntu server guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/openldap-server.html) to configure OpenLDAP on an Ubuntu 10.04 server, but can not get it to work.

When I try to use `sudo ldapadd -x -D cn=admin,dc=don,dc=com -W -f frontend.ldif` I'm getting the following error:

```
Enter LDAP Password: <entered 'secret' as password>
adding new entry "dc=don,dc=com"
ldap_add: Naming violation (64)
      additional info: value of single-valued naming attribute 'dc' conflicts with value present in entry
```

Again when I try to do the same, I'm getting the following error:

```
root@avy-desktop:/home/avy# sudo ldapadd -x -D cn=admin,dc=don,dc=com -W -f frontend.ldif
Enter LDAP Password:
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

---

Here is the `backend.ldif` file:

```
# Load dynamic backend modules
dn: cn=module,cn=config
objectClass: olcModuleList
cn: module
olcModulepath: /usr/lib/ldap
olcModuleload: back_hdb

# Database settings
dn: olcDatabase=hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcHdbConfig
olcDatabase: {1}hdb
olcSuffix: dc=don,dc=com
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap
olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=don,dc=com
olcRootPW: secret
olcDbConfig: set_cachesize 0 2097152 0
olcDbConfig: set_lk_max_objects 1500
olcDbConfig: set_lk_max_locks 1500
olcDbConfig: set_lk_max_lockers 1500
olcDbIndex: objectClass eq
olcLastMod: TRUE
olcDbCheckpoint: 512 30
olcAccess: to attrs=userPassword by dn="cn=admin,dc=don,dc=com" write by anonymous auth by self write by * none
olcAccess: to attrs=shadowLastChange by self write by * read
olcAccess: to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: to * by dn="cn=admin,dc=don,dc=com" write by * read
```

---

`frontend.ldif` file:

```
# Create top-level object in domain
dn: dc=don,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectclass: organization
o: Example Organization
dc: Example
description: LDAP Example 

# Admin user.
dn: cn=admin,dc=don,dc=com
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
objectClass: organizationalRole
cn: admin
description: LDAP administrator
userPassword: secret

dn: ou=people,dc=don,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: people

dn: ou=groups,dc=don,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: groups

dn: uid=john,ou=people,dc=don,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: shadowAccount
uid: john
sn: Doe
givenName: John
cn: John Doe
displayName: John Doe
uidNumber: 1000
gidNumber: 10000
userPassword: password
gecos: John Doe
loginShell: /bin/bash
homeDirectory: /home/john
shadowExpire: -1
shadowFlag: 0
shadowWarning: 7
shadowMin: 8
shadowMax: 999999
shadowLastChange: 10877
mail: john.doe@don.com
postalCode: 31000
l: Toulouse
o: Example
mobile: +33 (0)6 xx xx xx xx
homePhone: +33 (0)5 xx xx xx xx
title: System Administrator
postalAddress:
initials: JD

dn: cn=example,ou=groups,dc=don,dc=com
objectClass: posixGroup
cn: example
gidNumber: 10000
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Anybody has any idea?

Comment: No one uses ldap?. Why even the documents are not working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

This [link](http://albanianwizard.org/ubuntu-10-0-4-lucid-lynx-ldap-configuration-the-working-how-to.albanianwizard) helped install LDAP without any error and had to edit only the starting lines 2,3 and 4. Just checked the ldap installation and configuration with webmin

Answer (score 0):

For me, your frontend.ldif seems to be invalid, where `dn` stated `dn: dc=don,dc=com` (so rdn is `dc=don`) but still, you use `dc: Example` later. I think you've tried to use a tutorial, but you forget to modify some parts of your ldif file, if dn is correct, you should use `dc: don` (the same as in dn). Also you mention backend.ldif (which seems to be modify some settings via config backend of slapd) and frontend.ldif but you only shows example that you try to add entries from frontend.ldif and not backend.ldif.

Comment: Yes, in the documnet it was `dc=example,dc=com` so I changed, but here `dc: Example` which is captical `E` and I thought it could be any name. I'll try that changing

Comment: I added backend file and it didn't give any error!

Comment: Still it gives the same error!